# How is the と　particle being used here?

Tags: grammar, particles, particle-と, particle-も, anime

I’m trying to understand the use of the と particle in the bellow quoted passage.

I understand the sentences overall, but am lacking a complete understanding that would be provided by understanding the use of the と particle.

Here is the passage [I've highlighted the とs that are causing me difficulty.]. It is an excerpt from Death Note [anime] episode 10*:

> L : キラは負けず嫌いだが、キラでなく**と**も試合に勝ちたいと思うのが大多数だ
>   Light: ムキになって勝ち抜く**と**キラっぽい…か？だからと言ってわざと負ければ、ムキになって勝ち抜く**と**キラっぽいと思われるからわざと負けるところがまだキラっぽい…だろ

The troublesome とs:

> ...キラでなく**と**も...抜く**と**キラっぽい... [the second one appears twice in the same sentence constellation]

Specifically, I don’t know if と being used as the natural consequences conditional or in one of its other uses linking up nouns with verbs, e.g. 友達と会う. I think what’s causing me trouble in differentiating the two uses in general is that I don’t really understand how 友達と会う is different from something like 友達にあう. Also, how, if at all, does the first と interact with the も?

If someone could clear up these queries, that would be awesome. Many thanks!

*Note on context:

> The characters are successively thinking to themselves about how to outsmart the other. The context is that they’re playing tennis, and thinking about how Light's behavior [he is suspected to be the killer] would affect his appearing like Kira. "Kira" [キラ] is the serial killer using the magic eponymous "Death Note" of the series to kill many people. Light is Kira and obviously knows this, so is considering how to outmaneuver L, who is on his trail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first one is not と+も but the particle とも. It is combined with preceding ない, then it becomes なくとも. This means "even if it is not (Kira)." なくとも is used only in writing. It's same as なくても, which is more common form.

http://www.japanese-edu.org.hk/sympo/schedule/Abstr/Abst071.html

と in 勝ち抜くと is used as the natural consequences conditional. It's same as 雨が降ると雪が解けます.

友達と会う and 友達にあう are same in most cases. The difference is, if I have to bring up one, 友達と会う means you and your friend are supposed to meet and 友達にあう means your friend doesn't know you are coming.

Comment: Great answer. Succint and answered all my questions.

Comment: Out of curiosity, would the above clause you said to be natural consequences と work as the other と?